# HERE Maps API - Toll

Tags: geocoding, here-api

Similar to finding petrol stations in a boundary box like this (using *q=petrol+station*):

```
https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?apiKey=XXXXX&in=bbox:-8.458019,38.065748,-8.351916,38.152380&q=petrol+station
```

(there should be two petrol stations and one toll location in the above area)

I would like to know if there is a comparable string I can use to find toll locations in an area, I have tried *toll*, *toll+booth* and *tollbooth*, all to no effect.

I have also tried browsing by [category](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-places/places-category-system-full.html) to find toll locations near a point:

```
https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?apiKey=XXXXX&at=38.11945,-8.41455&categories=400-4100
```

(the coordinates *38.11945,-8.41455* itself is the point of a toll location)

So if there is a way that I can find the coordinates of toll locations in an area or near a point, please let me know.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no coverage for Tollbooth in the specified region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Overpass API from OpenStreetMap](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API):

```
https://overpass.kumi.systems/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];area["ISO3166-1"="ZA"][admin_level=2];(node["barrier"="toll_booth"](area);way["barrier"="toll_booth"](area);rel["barrier"="toll_booth"](area););out center;
```

The above finds all `node`, `way` and `rel` that are tagged with `barrier=toll_booth` in `ZA` (South Africa).